# Test class for Einstein OCR service

Tags: apex, code-coverage

We are hitting Einstein OCR to predict an image. When we tried to write test class for it we are always getting this error in developer console.

```
Go to Setup and Configuration on the Einstein Admin tab to configure access to your Einstein.ai account
```

Here is my Apex class

```
public with sharing class CommonOCR {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static WrapperWithImageTypeAndPredection getPredictData(String imageData,String OCRType) { 
        
        String MODELID =  OCRType.toLowercase() == 'table' ? 'tabulatev2':'OCRModel'; 
        String TASK =  OCRType.toLowercase() == 'table' ? 'table':'Contact' ;    
      
        String SAMPLEID = '';
            einsteinplay.Einstein_PredictionService einsteinService = new einsteinplay.Einstein_PredictionService(
                einsteinplay.Einstein_PredictionService.Types.OCR
            );
           
            einsteinplay.Einstein_PredictionResult response = einsteinService.predictOcrBase64(MODELID,
                imageData,
                TASK,
                SAMPLEID
            );
          
            List<OCRWrapper> lstOCRWrapper=new List<OCRWrapper>();
            for (einsteinplay.Einstein_Probability probability: response.probabilities) {
                if( OCRType.toLowercase() == 'table')
                {
                 lstOCRWrapper.add(new OCRWrapper(probability.label,probability.boundingBox?.maxX,probability.boundingBox?.maxY,probability.boundingBox?.minX,probability.boundingBox?.minY,probability.attributes.cellLocation?.rowIndex,probability.attributes.cellLocation?.colIndex)) ;   
                }
                else{
                 lstOCRWrapper.add(new OCRWrapper(probability.label,probability.boundingBox?.maxX,probability.boundingBox?.maxY,probability.boundingBox?.minX,probability.boundingBox?.minY)) ;   
                }                          
              }
           
              einsteinService = new einsteinplay.Einstein_PredictionService(
                einsteinplay.Einstein_PredictionService.Types.IMAGE
            );
            einsteinplay.Einstein_PredictionResult result = einsteinService.predictImageBase64(
                        'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                        imageData,
                        0,
                        ''
                    );
            return (new WrapperWithImageTypeAndPredection(lstOCRWrapper,result.probabilities[0].label));
    }

    public class OCRWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled public string label {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Integer maxX {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Integer maxY {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Integer minX {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Integer minY {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Integer colIndex {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Integer rowIndex {get; set;}
 
        //This is the contructor method. When we create a new wrapAccount object we pass a Account that is set to the acc property. We also set the selected value to false
        public OCRWrapper(string label,Integer maxX,Integer maxY,
        Integer minX,Integer minY,Integer rowIndex,Integer colIndex) {
            this.label = label;
            this.maxX = maxX;
            this.maxY=maxY;
            this.minX=minX;
            this.miny=minY;
            this.rowIndex=rowIndex;
            this.colIndex=colIndex;
        }

        public OCRWrapper(string label,Integer maxX,Integer maxY,Integer minX,Integer minY) {
            this.label = label;
            this.maxX = maxX;
            this.maxY=maxY;
            this.minX=minX;
            this.miny=minY;     
        }
    }

    public class WrapperWithImageTypeAndPredection{
            @AuraEnabled public List<OCRWrapper> OCRPredicton {get; set;}
            @AuraEnabled public string imageType {get; set;}
            public WrapperWithImageTypeAndPredection(List<OCRWrapper> OCRPredicton ,string imageType)
            {
                this.OCRPredicton=OCRPredicton;
                this.imageType=imageType;
            }
        }
}
```

and my test class

```
@isTest
public with sharing class CommonOCR_Test {
    @isTest static void CommonOCR_Positive() {
      
        String imageData='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';
        String OCRType='table';
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Einstein_HttpMockResponses_Test());
        CommonOCR.WrapperWithImageTypeAndPredection owrapper=CommonOCR.getPredictData(imageData,OCRType);
    }
}
```